# Internationalization of file names in applescript

Tags: macos, internationalization, applescript

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002311/delete-multiple-files-with-applescript/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20004019/1661012), this a problem I encounter often. How can I tell applescript to correctly understand the file names I’m giving it, i.e. understand all characters, not just ASCII ones.

Comment: How so? Could you elaborate? Those seem to deal with sorting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read and write commands still default to the "primary encoding", like MacRoman or MacJapanese. You can use UTF-8 by adding `as «class utf8»`:

```
$ printf äあ>/tmp/a
$ osascript -e 'read "/tmp/a"'
√§„ÅÇ
$ osascript -e 'read "/tmp/a" as «class utf8»'
äあ
```

`as Unicode text` is UTF-16.

Comment: Why do you make this more complicated than necessary? Given OP's situation, saving the file as UTF8 should me sufficient.

Comment: @Mark /tmp/a is encoded as UTF-8 in my example, but the first read command reads it as MacRoman. You need to add `as «class utf8»` to read the file as UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, but all that isn't necessary. Why even use the shell in your example?

Comment: `as «class utf8»` was exactly what I needed. Thank you.